# Bootstrap-Switch options don't take effect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using Bootstrap-Switch and the documentation says that options can be passed as an object on initialization.  [enter link description here](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/)

And here is a list of options: [enter link description here](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/documentation-3.html)

So my code looks like this:

```
var options = {
    onText: "Yes",
    onColor: 'primary',
    offColor: 'danger',
    offText: "No",
    animate: true,
};

$("[name='radioGroup1']").bootstrapSwitch(options);
```

And it all switch works fine, but none of the defaults are overwritten by the options.

Anybody got any examples of how this might work?

Comment: The image link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was I hadn't checked which version of Bootstrap-Switch I was using. Above code works fine in Version 3